# Sorting numerical values in R

Tags: r, sorting

[image]

If you look at the legend page, clusters 0 and 1 are followed by 10 and 11 ~.
I don't know how to sort in the order 0, 1, 2, 3~.

My code :

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = PT, y = Value, fill=Cluster)) +
geom_bar(position="fill", stat = "identity") +
scale_fill_manual(values = getPalette(colourCount)) +
theme_classic()
```

Comment: Please insert your images as embeded elements, not as links.

Comment: my account can't do that function yet